# How to use Scintilla for Unicode strings

Tags: c++, webkit, scintilla

I set the codepage to UTF8 with `SCI_SETCODEPAGE` before using scintilla but scintilla is not treating strings as Unicode. I’m seeing some code which is actually explicitly converting the `lparam` data into `char *`.

Do I need to do some additional settings to get the scintilla working for Unicode strings?

Comment: UTF8 != Unicode, I think you need to be a little clearer about what you are expecting. I don't know scintilla, but if you've selected UTF8 I would expect it to convert to `char*`. Perhaps you want UTF16?

Answer (score 2):

When you say you're using Scintilla do you mean you're actually using SciTE, the text editor based on the Scintilla text editing library? I use SciTE, and I have it set to encode in UTF-8. This is done by adding the following property in one of your options files:

```
code.page=65001
```

For example, just paste that in Options -> Open User Options File and save it.

Comment: Actually I have an application(vc++) which is using scintilla for writing text messages in the edit control. My application has set the codepage to SC_CP_UTF8 through code for scintilla and sending Unicode strings to scintilla but scintilla is not generating any output.

Comment: @user2357709 The important question is what you mean by 'unicode strings'.

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't exactly sure of your scenario. I haven't used Scintilla myself. Are you sure you're using the correct format ie SC_CP_UTF8 (65001) or SCI_SETCODEPAGE(65001). Have you seen the [documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETCODEPAGE)?

Comment: My application is maintaining strings in TCHAR format. This string is sent to scintilla with post message in lparam. Scintilla has support for Unicode in utf8 format. From my application, I’m using  Call(SCI_SETCODEPAGE, SC_CP_UTF8, 0); Call is a function pointer to a function in scintilla library which is setting the codepage to  SC_CP_UTF8(65001). Here the problem is scintilla is not generating any string.

Comment: Here the problem is scintilla is *not generating any string

Comment: Unfortunately TCHAR format means different things depending on what build settings you have. Do you know if you are doing a Unicode build or an ANSI build?

Comment: OK, well my reading of the documentation is that setting means you must *supply* data in UTF-8, but from what you've said you are supplying UTF-16. So I think you need to do the UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion yourself.